# JavaScript popup for every page in a domain

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a JavaScript popup (say, with Shadowbox.js) one time, and have it pop up on every page within a domain?

Comment: absolutely. very possible. please show what you have so far and how your site is built, frameworks and tech stack etc. then update the tags

Comment: You could create the popup script and include that script in every page.  Is that not what you are wanting?  `<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Create the js file and include Your .js file to the common header of your site.
such as
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>`